# Inductor Datasheet (Inductance No DC)

Tags: inductor, datasheet, toroid

Can anyone please help me understand what is Inductance (Typical) and Inductance No DC in the datasheet of inductors from Pulse Electronics?

[The link for datasheet for toroid inductors of Pulse Electronics](https://html.alldatasheet.com/html-pdf/654075/PULSE/PE-51517/151/1/PE-51517.html)

[image: The image of the datasheet for further reference.]

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: DC causes the operation point on the BH curve to shift. So if you’re using the inductor for a buck or boost converter, then expect less inductance vs , say, an AC LC filter.

Comment: @Kartman Thanks for the info. Then accordingly if the inductor is used for high frequency AC with no DC offset then, 'Inductance with No DC' should be considered, right?

Comment: That’s correct.